# Adding constraints to my fitting model using lmfit

Tags: python, constraints, curve-fitting, model-fitting, lmfit

I want to fit a model using lmfit. The model has 2 parameters c and c1. For these parameters, i have 3 constraints (0<=c<=1) (-1<=c1<=0) and (1+c1-c>0). How do I incorporate these constraints to my model?

I was trying the following method:

```
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add("c1", value = -0.5, min = -1, max = 0)
params.add("constraint", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1)
params.add("c", expr = "1+c1-constraint", min = 0, max = 1)
```

In this, the constraint on c1 and 1+c1-c were followed but the constraint on c is not being followed in fitting. Whenever the constraint is not followed, the output of c is just coming out to be 0, which is creating problems in my fitting. What should I do?

Comment: please edit your three constraints to be readable: `(0<=c<=1)` is clearly a constraint, and it looks like you have that encoded correctly.  `(-1<=0<=1)` is  "always true" ;),  and `(1+c1-c>)` is an invalid expression.  It looks to me like you are on the right track.

Comment: Corrected the constraints

Answer (score 0):

I probably would have written that as

```py
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add("c1", value=0, min=-1, max=0) # (-1<=c1<=0) 
params.add("delta", value=0.5, min=0)   # (1+c1+delta = c, delta>0)
params.add("c", expr="1+c1+delta", min=0, max=1) # (0<=c<=1)
```

Does that seem right to you?

Comment: The fitting method i am using needs both lower and upper bounds for the constraints so this won't work. Also, this has the same issue where output of c will just be changed to a boundary value whenever the constraint on c is not followed.

Comment: You can add an upper bound on `delta` or `constraint`.  I'm afraid I don't understand the other part of your question or comment. For `c`, the expression will be evaluated, and then bounds will be applied. For sure, any parameter with bounds can have its value get stuck at a boundary - you are basically asserting that it should get stuck at a limit instead of violating that limit.   It is definitely possible that the limits will be the best value with some models and some data.

Comment: What I am saying it is like i am getting something like -0.8 for c1, 0.7 for constraint and 0 for c. So, it is varying constraint and c1 and is not varying c at all (because 1+c1-constraint should be -0.5). I want it so that c and c1 are varied such that constraint is obeyed. If i make the constraint in terms of c and c1, then the constraint is not obeyed. What to do?

Comment: Well, yeah you did actually set a lower bound of 0 on `c1`.  ;)  There are lots of values for `c` and `constraint` where `c1` would be negative (I think none where `c1>1`).    You have not said anything about how you decided that `c1` is -0.8 and `constraint` is 0.7.

Comment: That was the output i got. c = 0, c1 = -0.8, constraint=0.7. If this is happening, the expression for the constraint is not even valid anymore

Comment: It is invalid because you selected those values for `c1` and `constraint` (how? doing some fit? why did you not describe that at all), and imposed the limit that `c>0`.  Perhaps you would want to explain what you are trying to do: how you got those values, why you think the limits are needed, and so forth.

Comment: Ok, so my model is the drude Smith Anderson model, which is a conductivity model that i am using for my research.

Comment: In this model, c1 is the expectation value of cosine of some angles that vary from 90 to 180°, so should lie between 0 and -1. As for c, it is fraction of localized charged carriers (so, it should vary from 0 to 1)

Comment: The constraint is related to the DC conductivity of the system (so it should be positive

Comment: So, when i define parameters as i have defined above and try fitting the function using lmfit.minimize using differential evolution method, i get the results i mentioned above (c1 = -0.8, constraint = 0.7 and c = 0), which as you said is invalid according to constraint i have defined

Comment: This is what I meant by saying that the value of c becomes 0 when the value of the constraint becomes weird (the code fits c1 and constraint and then calculates the value of c from the constraint. If it is greater than 0, then it takes that as the value otherwise it takes 0 as the value

Comment: So, how can I fit my function such that all my constraints are followed?

Comment: 6 separate comments are not more likely to inspire someone to go out of their way to help you than 1 comment.  I think you have sort of exhausted my inspiration. In the future you probably want to follow the SO guidelines and post a minimal working example of what you are trying to do and discuss that.  It seems you are trying to fit some data to a model with lmfit.  But you asked (only, and exactly) about defining parameter constraints.  That question was answered.   You never actually showed any other code,  for example showing how such parameters are used.